# Ajax no llega al controlador en cakephp

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp, controller, router

Hola tengo los siguientes codigos : 
Routes

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'home', 'home'));
Router::connect('/post', array('controller' => 'Posts', 'action' => 'display', 'Posts/index'));
Router::connect('/admin', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'admin' => true));

/**
 * ...and connect the rest of 'Pages' controller's URLs.
 */
Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));
```

Js

```
    $(".btnFormNeed").on("click", function () {
    if ($.validador()) {
        var parametros = {
            "NeedClient": $(".txtClient").val(),
            "NeedNeed": $(".txtNeed").val(),
            "NeedObjective": $(".txtObjective").val()
        };
        $.ajax({
            data: parametros,
            url: '/',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                if(response==="si"){
                    //logica para avanzar a la siguiente vista de cake, la cual no se como se haced desde Jquery
                } else{
                    //sacar mensaje flash de cake desde jquery lo cual tampoco se. 
                }
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log("error");
            }
        });
    }

});
```

Se supone que con eso voy a insertar los datos del formulario, la cosa es que no se que debo cambiarle para que llegue a la url, la vista es home, les mostre routes ps ahi se ve cual es la ruta del controller de home, y no si hay algo que debo cambiar para que inserte.

PagesController

```
public function home() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        if (!empty($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Flash->error(__("Emty"));
            $this->loadModel('Need');

            $this->Need->create();
            if ($this->Need->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Need->save(array(
                    'date' => date("Y/m/d")
                ));

                $this->set('doctor', "si");
            }
            $this->set('doctor', "no");
        } else {
            $this->set('doctor', "no");
        }
    } else {
        $this->set('doctor', "no");
    }
}
```

Ese es el controlador, la cosa es que no se leer bien los paramatros que le envie por metodo post, para insertarlos en la base de datos, en php puro los leeria `$_POST["NeedClient"]; $_POST["NeedNeed"]; $_POST["NeedObjective"];`  pero en cake no se como hacerlo.

Home - vista

```
    <div id="divNeeds" class="row" hidden="true">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-5">
                <h1 id="h1NeedsTitle" class="lang" key="h1NeedsTitle">Descubrir necesidades</h1>
                <h4 class="lang" key="h4FNeedsFirstText">
                    El comienzo de una estratégia funcional es conoces nuestro <br>
                    objetivo y que necesidades queremos resolver, de esta forma <br>
                    nuestro equipo a través de un laboratorio enlaza un vínculo con <br>
                    la marca y da comienzo al plan estrategico.
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1">
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <?php
                echo $this->Form->create('Need', array('class' => '', 'id' => 'msform'));
                ?>
                <h1 class="lang" key="h1NeedForm">Aprovechemos el tiempo y comencemos</h1>
                <?php
                echo $this->Form->input('client', array('label' => array('text' => "¿Para que marca vamos a trabahar?",
                        'key' => 'lblClient', 'class' => 'lang'), 'placeholder' => 'Dinos el nombre de tu empresa',
                    'class' => 'validador txtClient lang', 'key' => 'txtClient'));
                echo $this->Form->input('need', array('label' => array('text' => "Escríbenos acerca de tu necesidad",
                        'key' => 'lblNeed', 'class' => 'lang'), 'placeholder' => 'Agradecemos nos detalles muy bien la necesidad, '
                    . 'es nuestro punto de partida para generar ideas quer fortalezcan la estrategia para resolverla.',
                    'rows' => '4', 'class' => 'validador txtNeed lang', 'key' => 'txtNeed', 'style' => 'resize: none;'));
                echo $this->Form->input('objective', array('label' => array('text' => "¿Cuál es el objetivo?",
                        'key' => 'lblObjective', 'class' => 'lang'), 'placeholder' => 'Que se quiere alcanzar con la'
                    . 'solución de la necesidad, ¿Adquirir usuario? ¿Mejorar ventas? ¿Posicionar la marca? ... entre otros.'
                    . ' Agradecemos nos detalles muy bien el objetivo.', 'rows' => '4',
                    'class' => 'validador txtObjective lang', 'key' => 'txtObjective', 'style' => 'resize: none;'));
                ?>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <label class="lang" key="lblAddNeed">Tienes otra necesidad </label>
                            <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/37/37240.png" class="imgAddNeed"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <?php
                            $options = array(
                                'class' => 'lang btnFormNeed',
                                'label' => 'Enviar y continuar',
                                'key' => 'btnFormNeed',
                                'type' => 'button'
                            );
                            echo $this->Form->end($options);
                            ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Si entendí bien, el problema es que la información del POST no está llegando al controlador?

Answer (score 0):

En tu función `ajax` le estás diciendo que la petición es de tipo *GET*, por lo que tu `$this->request->data` está vacío, cambia el tipo a `POST`

```
$(".prueba").on("click", function () {
    console.log("hola");
    var parametros = {
        "doctorName": $(".doctorTitle").text(),
        "loActivo": "Si"
    };
    console.log("111");
    $.ajax({
        data: parametros,
        url: '/',
        type: 'POST', // Aquí le decimos que la petición es de tipo POST
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function () {
            $("#resultado").html("Procesando, espere por favor...");
        },
        success: function (response) {
            // Tu lógica a seguir de acuerdo a la respuesta obtenida
            console.log("1"+response+"1");
            console.log("2"+respose.data.items.doctor+"2");
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("error");
        }
    });
});
```

Y en el método del controlador tu validación del data está al revés

```
public function home() {
    // Revisamos si la petición es POST
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        // Revisamos si la petición POST tiene datos
        if (!empty($this->request->data)) {
            $this->loadModel('Need');
            $this->Need->create();
            if ($this->Need->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Need->save(array(
                    'date' => date("Y/m/d")
                ));
            }

            $this->set('prueba', 'HOLAAA');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: y si voy a enviar los datos por Ajax com leo esos datos en el controlador?

Comment: Si los envías con GET están en `$this->request->query`

Comment: Voy a hacerle un cambio a la pregunta

Comment: ya la edite, miren si saben como ayudarme y gracias de ante mano.

Answer (score 0):

**pequeña guia**

**1.- INSERTAR LA LIBRERÍA DE JQUERY**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
```

**2.- EL FORMULARIO**

Tener una vista o un HTML donde tengás un formulario.
En el formulario habrá que crear un identificador para el select option en este caso he puesto:

```
<select id="select_categoria">
      <option value="1">categoria1</option>
      <option value="2">categoria2</option>
      <option value="3">categoria3</option>
    </select>
```

También habrá que crear un div o un p para que cuando se devuelva el select option con las subcategorias se pinten en dentro de un html.

```
<div id="div_subcategorias_wrapper"></div>
```

**3.- LAS FUNCIONES JQUERY**
El id que hemos puesto al select option de las categorías se utiliza para que jquery haga un bindeo a una determinada acción que nosotros especifiquemos.

```
$("document").ready(
function() {

    $('#select_categoria').bind('click', function()
    {
        $.ajax({
               type: "GET",
               url: "/articulos/obtener_subcategorias/"+$(this).val(),
               beforeSend: function() {
                     $('#div_subcategorias_wrapper').html('<div class="rating-flash" id="cargando_div">Cargando  <img src="/img/ajax-loader_mini.gif"></div>');
                     },
               success: function(msg){
                   $('#div_subcategorias_wrapper').html(msg);
               }
             });
    });

}
);
```

**4.- El CONTROLADOR O LA LÓGICA DE PHP**

```
<?php
class ArticulosController extends AppController
{
    var $uses = array('Articulo','ArticuloCategoria','ArticuloSubcategoria');
    function index()
    {
        // lógica
    }

    function obtener_subcategorias($id)
    {
        $this->layout = 'ajax';
        // aquí la lógica que uséis para obtener datos de la <a href="https://www.pedroventura.com/tag/base-de-datos/" data-wpel-link="internal">base de datos</a>
        // y generar un array con todas las categorías
        // por lo normal y rápido será usar la funcion find con el primer parámetro list para que lo devuelva formateado con el identificador de cada opcion como key de los nodos del array
        $subcategorias = $this->ArticuloSubcategoria->find('list',array('conditions' => array('ArticuloSubcategoria.categoria_id' => $id), 'fields' => 'nombre_subcategoria'));
        $this->set('listado_subcategorias',$subcategorias);
    }

}
?>
```

**5.- RENDERIZAR EL SELECT OPTION EN LA VISTA**

```
<? echo $form->input('Articulo.id_subcategoria', array('options' => $listado_subcategorias,'label'=>false,'div'=>null));?>
```

espero haberte ayudado:

[Guia completa](http://miftyisbored.com/a-complete-tutorial-on-cakephp-and-ajax-forms-using-jquery/)

[Plugin Ajax para CakePhp](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-ajax)

Comment: Voy a probar y les cuento, aunque debo decir que no entiendo en el controlador como obtienes en el controlador los datos que enviaste por get

Comment: Metiendo en url pages/home/ sale esto: `http://mipagina.com.co/pages/home 404 (Not Found)`